# Unable to make calls with Valence API

Tags: php, desire2learn, valence

I'm new to the Valence API and Desire2Learn/Brightspace and I'm unable to make successful API calls. Currently I'm using the language bindings at the [Valence Site](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/clients/index.html), and can authenticate properly. However, I have made the "Get Versions" call to work sometimes, but I have not been able to make any other call, even while using the user credentials that are supplied. Any other call and I receive a 400 Bad Request header.

All of the fields are left as the defaults, including the host which is "valence.desire2learn.com". If anybody can help solve my issue I would immensely appreciate it.

EDIT: I discovered that my problems lie with the server that I was testing against. If I change the host parameter to the URL that the API test tool uses (devcop.brightspacedemo.com), I can make API calls again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host you mention is a public test, demo site. The fact that you can make a GET versions call (which only needs to be made anonymously), but no other call leads me to wonder if you have appropriate user credentials for that site?

Comment: Hi @Viktor. I've only been using the user credentials supplied with the sample application I'm using, and following the authentication process required in order to make API calls to the site. This only fails when I use "valence.desire2learn.com" as the host. However, if I use the host from the API Test Tool everything works fine.

Comment: User credentials are specific Brightspace Tenant to Brightspace Tenant: it's entirely possible that a 'TestUser' account on one LMS will have a different password on another.

Comment: The only credentials I'm using are already supplied with the client SDK that I downloaded from the site. Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: Which language SDK package are you using?

Comment: I just added an edit to my original post. It seems that if I change the host parameter to the same one that the API test tool uses at https://apitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com, then everything seems to work okay. Right now I'm only experiencing issues with the test server at valence.desire2learn.com.

Comment: My guess is that's because valence.desire2learn.com is an old test instance that is no longer in step with the credentials in the samples available on GitHub.

Comment: Right now that seems like it makes sense since I'm only having problems when I test with that server. I will go ahead and mark your post as the answer. Thank you!